# Loop CSS typewriter effect and change text

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I need to loop through the CSS typewriter effect, and change the text for each loop. Here is the code I'm using for the typewriter effect. I'm guessing I need to use javascript, but I am not sure how to go about this. Any ideas on how I could do this?

[Snippet Reference](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/)

```css
.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
  typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
  blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}


body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
    blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: blue; }
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>The cat and the hat.</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a note: your code is copy pasted from: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect/. Mentioning your source is a nice thing to do. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you will need some script, at least to detect the end of the animations. Then to refresh html content,you can store all the messages to display in an array and loop through it. Then you have to adjust the speed, depending on the length of the text displayed.

```js
var messages=["message1","message2  message2 message2","message3 message3"];
var rank=0;

// Code for Chrome, Safari and Opera
document.getElementById("myTypewriter").addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", changeTxt);

// Standard syntax
document.getElementById("myTypewriter").addEventListener("animationend", changeTxt);

function changeTxt(e){
  _h1 = this.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
  _h1.style.webkitAnimation = 'none'; // set element animation to none
   setTimeout(function() { // you surely want a delay before the next message appears
      _h1.innerHTML=messages[rank];
      var speed =3.5*messages[rank].length/20; // adjust the speed (3.5 is the original speed, 20 is the original string length
      _h1.style.webkitAnimation = 'typing '+speed+'s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite'; //  switch to the original set of animation      
      (rank===messages.length-1)?rank=0:rank++; // if you have displayed the last message from the array, go back to the first one, else go to next message
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
  typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
  blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}


body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: blue; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="typewriter" id="myTypewriter">
  <h1>The cat and the hat.</h1>
</div>
```

also check for the different syntax https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_animation.asp

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via jQuery (or JavaSript, if you prefer).  Simply, wait till the animation is done, then replace the containing HTML.

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  $(".typewriter").html("<h1>This is a really cool string</h1>")
},3500);
```

```css
.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
  typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
  blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}


body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding-top: 5em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* DEMO-SPECIFIC STYLES */
.typewriter h1 {
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
    blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 100% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: blue; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="typewriter">
  <h1>The cat and the hat.</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You do not NEED javascript for this.**

Do not be fooled. This can be done with CSS only, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57887588/2397550 for a working example. You could split the CSS animation into several individual ones and execute them after each other with `animation-delay`.

A(nother) downside to your solution is that it requires a monospaced font, which is a limitation I would not like to have.