# animate text as writing in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Check the code bellow. Here i am trying to animate a text which will be iterate over and over again without click button. First part of code works on click button but second part not works where i removed function and added it in jquery ready() method. It should be work on document ready but its not working. Whats wrong i am doing here?

This is what working now on click button:

```
<h1>Typewriter</h1>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
</script>
```

This is what i tried already:

```
    <span id="demo"></span>

$(document).ready(function () {
        typeWriter();
        //writing effect
        var i = 0;
        var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
        var speed = 50;
        function typeWriter() {
            if (i < txt.length) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
                i++;
                setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
            }
        }

        });
```

Comment: In your second block `typeWriter` is not defined. Please edit your second code block to show the whole file, like you do in the first code block. That will make it more clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop CSS typewriter effect and change text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42822040/loop-css-typewriter-effect-and-change-text)

Comment: Question updated as u asked @Reed Spool

Comment: @kmoser no your reference is not same effect as it does. this one more simple

Comment: you are calling your function `typeWriter();` before `txt` is intialize you can check you might be getting error `length` is not defined for `txt`.Instead call that function after `var speed = 50; //call typeWriter();` it should work .

Comment: 1. Why do you need `$(document).ready()`? 
This is `jquery`. 2. `typeWriter()` should be placed after logic when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i call typeWriter() function after just its defined then it works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 0;
            var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
            var speed = 100;
            function typeWriter() {
                if (i < txt.length) {
                    document.getElementById("secondLineTxt").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
                }
            }
            typeWriter();

});
```

Comment: Please debug your browser console. Maybe some hints?

Comment: my bad. i was not checking browser console

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

//writing effect
        var i = 0;
        var txt = 'Lorem ipsum dummy text blabla.';
        var speed = 50;
        function typeWriter() {
            if (i < txt.length) {
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
                i++;
                setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
            }
}

        typeWriter();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Typewriter</h1>
<button>Click me</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```